# What file format can I use to output a formatted text file straight from a program without having the markup be too complicated?

Tags: java, file-io, file-format

**Premise:**

I am parsing a file that is quite nearly XML, but not quite. From this file I would like to extract data and output in a file that a user could open up in some program and read. To make the data reasonable, I would almost certainly need to format the text. In case it matters, I will probably be using Java to write the program.

**Problem:**

I cannot find a file format that supports formatting without having terribly complex rules and encoding problems.

**Attempts:**

- I looked into a basic .txt extension first, but it does not have enough formatting advantage.
- I then tried a .rtf extension, but the rules for outputting text seem to be terribly complicated.
- It was then suggested that I used XML, but I do not understand how this file would be viewed. This appears to be probably the best solution, but I don't understand much about it. Perhaps somebody could shed some light here.

**In Other Words:**

Could somebody suggest and easy to use file format and/or shed some light on how to use XML for text formatting and viewing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about plain HTML? simple formatting, readable everywheree.

Comment: +1 Yeah, I feel a little silly overlooking this. Thank you, I will select this as the answer ASAP.

Comment: Or if you like XML, use XHTML.

Answer (score 3):

XML is good, and most web browsers have some kind of tree-like xml display.

Another option might be to use comma-separated values, make up some structure, and import into Excel or other spreadsheet for viewing.

(edit -- For various reasons, I was gravitating towards something that was also machine readable, like a downstream tool might like it. The other answer of HTML is also excellent!)

Comment: +1 Good suggestions that may help for the future, but I think the HTML is what I was looking for :0)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/). It is quite simple and easy to read.

Comment: I'll look into this a bit... How does one view a YAML file?

Comment: As a plain text file with Notepad or MS Word